# Lasso in R: cv.glmnet() running extremely slowly

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I have a 7187x4877 dataframe in R. I've converted it to a matrix successfully and am trying to run cv.glmnet(). It's been running for over 20 minutes. The size of the matrix is 268 mb.

This is the 3rd time I've tried running it. The previous times, I've had to use my task manager to exit RStudio because it wouldn't close otherwise. Any suggestions?

```
trainx <- as.matrix(train[,-4710])
trainy <- as.matrix(train[,4710])

cv.lasso <- cv.glmnet(trainx, trainy, alpha = 1)
```

Comment: Hey.. there's a few ways, but why not you try it with one or two lambda, run it with the option lambda = c(0.1,0.01) .. and see how long that takes. Then you can estimate with the default number of lambdas how much time is required

Comment: So, there are a few ways to reduce that, 1. reduce the number of columns you have. 2. set parallel = TRUE but be careful you have the ram ! 3. reduce the number of folds, maybe nfolds=5 .. you have to play around with this... but the strategy is to estimate about how much time you need for 1..